# On ubuntu, having installed rvm and ruby 1.9.2 why does bundle give error after repo checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, bundler

Having installed rvm ok, when running 'bundle' it seems to install underneath the application in a 'development' directory:

```
/home/oceanician/dev/anythingon/development/ruby/1.9.1
```

I thought this might be the development environment setting!

Worse still this is ruby 1.9.1, and we've only installed ruby 1.9.2 under rvm.

```
which ruby
/home/oceanician/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
```

Odder, whilst /usr/bin/ruby exists, -v gives:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

rvm list gives:

```
=* ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i686 ]
```

rvm gemset list gives:

```
anythingon
```

Anyway,so I thought it must be the rvm gemset path somehow?
rvm gemset gemdir gives:

```
/home/oceanician/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@anythingon
```

Running any rails command obviously errors. Here's that:
rails s
/home/oceanician/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.0.21]

My Gemfile specifies rails 3.1.0, and has NO development specific settings!

Any clues? It's late here, so probably doing something daft. Will have a look back in 9 hours or so. Any help appreciated. Cheers, Ian.

Comment: Having gems install to 1.9.1 dir isn't a problem (for some reason that was explained to me once but didn't make much sense, this is what it's supposed to do). And the `which ruby` looks right (don't use the one in /usr/bin). Your path looks right since `which ruby` returns the right value. So I'm not really sure what the issue is, but wonder what would happen if you said `bundle exec rails s` and also wondering what it says when you type `gem which rails`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok - cheers for ideas.

right, `bundle config`, gives us where the settings are coming form.

Looking in the project directory file. `.bundle/config` the *path* is set to development.

removing the `.bundle` directory and re-running  `bundle install` will sort this particular problem! Cheers to @mikejospheson

Also see: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-0-stable/ISSUES.md